# Syntax error unexpected '=', expecting variable when upgrading to Magento CE 2.4.3 / php7.4.27 / Composer

Tags: php, magento2

Setup:di compile throws and error after upgrade

My environment is ubuntu 18, Magento CE 2.4.3 and the error is as below. Tried deleting the composer.lock, removing the vendor folder, running composer update and composer install. Error persists and compile fails. What else can I try?

```
1/9 [===>------------------------]  11% < 1 sec 145.0 MiBsyntax error, unexpected '=', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)#0 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#1 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call()
#3 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(134): class_exists()
#4 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(117): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->includeClass()
#5 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(87): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->extract()
#6 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/RepositoryGenerator.php(61): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->getList()
#7 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(56): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\RepositoryGenerator->doOperation()
#8 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php(216): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process()
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute()
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()
#14 /var/www/html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#15 {main}
```

Tried forcing php 7.4.27 and php 7.4.21 in my composer.json

```
name     : psr/log
descrip. : Common interface for logging libraries
keywords : log, psr, psr-3
versions : * 1.1.4
type     : library
license  : MIT License (MIT) (OSI approved)
https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT.html#licenseText
homepage : https://github.com/php-fig/log
source   : [git] https://github.com/php-fig/log.git
d49695b909c3b7628b6289db5479a1c204601f11
dist     : [zip] https://api.github.com/repos/php
fig/log/zipball/d49695b909c3b7628b6289db5479a1c204601f11
d49695b909c3b7628b6289db5479a1c204601f11
path     : /var/www/html/vendor/psr/log
names    : psr/log
support
source : https://github.com/php-fig/log/tree/1.1.4
autoload
psr-4
Psr\Log\ => Psr/Log/
requires
php >=5.3.0
```

Comment: What version of Composer are you running? Requirements for Magento 2.4.3 (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html) specify it is compatible with Composer v2.

Comment: Composer version 2.2.4 2022-01-08 12:30:42

Answer (score 0):

A friend helped me trace the error back to an actual syntax error in

`app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php on line 156` 
isLast needs to be $isLast